# cannot run traceview in eclipse for android profiling

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, profiling

I click the profile threads to start and after stopping profiling I get a new tab with this:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Method exit (android/os/Debug.isMethodTracingActive ()Z) does not match current method (dalvik/system/VMDebug.isMethodTracingActive ()Z)
at com.android.traceview.ThreadData.exit(ThreadData.java:106)
at com.android.traceview.DmTraceReader.parseData(DmTraceReader.java:323)
at com.android.traceview.DmTraceReader.generateTrees(DmTraceReader.java:92)
at com.android.traceview.DmTraceReader.<init>(DmTraceReader.java:87)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview.editors.TraceviewEditor.createPartControl(TraceviewEditor.java:258)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPartHelper(EditorReference.java:670)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(EditorReference.java:465)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:595)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.getEditor(EditorReference.java:289)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditorBatched(WorkbenchPage.java:2945)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2850)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$11(WorkbenchPage.java:2842)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$10.run(WorkbenchPage.java:2793)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2789)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2773)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2756)
at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditorOnFileStore(IDE.java:1155)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview.TraceviewLauncher$1.run(TraceviewLauncher.java:65)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3563)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3212)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2701)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2665)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
```

instead of the profiling view

Any idea which library is missing or is of an invalid version? I have eclipse 3.7.2 with latest andoid version 20.0.3 and platform tools 14 and use Android 4.0.3 in my project.
OS Ubuntu 12.04 64 bits. I get the same error with both the Sun hotspot and OpenJDK.

Answer (score 1):

Do you run your app inside Intel x86 Emulator image?

If yes, this might be the reason. At least I just was bitten by this error, but when I tried to repeat profiling inside an ARM based emulator image all went well, everything works there!